# Django Deployment

Tags: django, deployment, tracking, release-management

I am given a responsibility in my project to develop a Equipment tracking tool with following requirements

1. New Equipment can be added by admin to a particular user
2. Once equipment is assigned to a person he will a request to accept the request so he will be responsible
3. User can transfer his equipment to other users.
4. At the same time Admin should be sent a mail or message whenever there is a change in status.
5. It should be deployed locally on a PC( So it is not actually a web app) that is connected to network which can be accessed by everyone

I thought I can use Django for this( I am new to it ), but I do not know much about deployment on a local PC , How can I do this, or is there any better Idea for this?

Comment: If this is a 'local' installation, are you planning on accessing it via a browser? What OS(es) do you have available for deployment? How many users will be accessing the application at once? These are all critical questions.

Comment: Yes we planning to access it via browser. We have windows XP for deployment, at a time max of 50 people will be accessing this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still sounds like you want a web app, you just won't be deploying it on a traditional web server.  One thing to note, client versions of Windows (XP, Vista) will limit you to 10 incoming connections per computer.

You'll want to follow these [instructions on how to install Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/#intro-install).  If you haven't installed python yet, I'll recommend that you [install version 2.5](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.2/), since that will include sqlite, an embedded database that makes it *very easy* to get started developing with Django.  Django includes its own development web server, which you will come across naturally as you [go through the tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01).

Start by installing and then jump right into the tutorial.  Your deployment options will be much easier to understand once you're comfortable with developing in Django.

Comment: Hi,

But my main concern is for the deployment on networked PC which is accessible through a network. How to do it?

Comment: @siri you have to setup the server on which you are deploying to be accessible by remote clients. For the development server to be remote accessible start your server by: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Answer (score 1):

Try http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/#howto-deployment-index

and if you should deploy using IIS then try http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer